# A question on graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Do there exist a family of graphs with $\Omega(N_{G}^{c})$ edges for some fixed $c > 0$ with the property:
$$\left|\alpha\left({G \boxtimes \bar{G}}\right) - \alpha\left({\overline{G \boxtimes \bar{G}}}\right)\right| = \theta(\log(N_{G}))$$
where $G$ is the graph, $\bar{G}$ is its complement, $\boxtimes$ denotes the strong product, $\alpha(G)$ denotes the independence number of $G$ and $N_{G}$ is the number of vertices of $G$?

Are there self-complementary family of graphs with the property:
$$\left|\alpha\left({G \boxtimes \bar{G}}\right) - \alpha\left({\overline{G \boxtimes \bar{G}}}\right)\right| = O(\log(N_{G}))?$$